# Как сделать конструктор пиццы, т.е. выбираешь какие-то ингредиенты и они добавляются на основной картинке как бы слоями сверху?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tools

Как на этих сайтах:

[500600.ru/vologda/constructor/pizza.html](http://500600.ru/vologda/constructor/pizza.html)

[amigo-pizza.ru/sozdaj-svoyu-pitstsu.html](http://amigo-pizza.ru/sozdaj-svoyu-pitstsu.html)

[dostavka.panda.su/designer](http://dostavka.panda.su/designer)

Answer (score 2):

Через две функции из jquery, click() и toggle(), и верстку по z-index.

Первая позволяет выполнить код при клике на элементе, вторая показать или скрыть ингредиент(то есть картинку). Соответственно z-index определит, что над чем должно находится.